# How to find a unary Tag name in XML using xml.etree.elementtree?

Tags: python, xml

I have below XML

```
<Instance>
 <Name>a</Name>
 <Type>
  <annual/>
 </Type> 
</Instance>
```

I am trying to get the name of "annual" between  but it's not value it's a unary tag name
I tried

```
xtree = et.parse(xml)
xroot = xtree.getroot() 
for node in xroot: 
    name = node.find("Type>").text
```

it's empty as no value there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
typenode = node.find("Type")
if typenode:
    # Get the tag of the first subnode
    name = typenode[0].tag
```

Fully working example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

xml="""
<xmldata>
  <Instance>
    <Name>First</Name>
    <Type>
      <annual/>
    </Type>
  </Instance>
  <Instance>
    <Name>Second</Name>
    <Type>
      <weekly/>
    </Type>
  </Instance>
</xmldata>
"""

xtree = et.fromstring(xml)
for instance in xtree:
    instancename = instance.find("Name").text
    type_node = instance.find("Type")
    sub_node = type_node[0]
    instancetype = sub_node.tag
    print("Instance {} is of type {}".format(instancename, instancetype))
```

Comment: Thank you Treuss, I tried this method but still  but still nothing printed 

for node in xroot: 
    typenode = node.find("paymentFrequency")
    if typenode:
    # Get the tag of the first subnode
        print(typenode[0].tag)
I also tried:
for node in xroot: 
    typenode = node.find("paymentFrequency")
    print(typenode[0].tag)

get error:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: So then your find is already not working.